# Brightness controls not working on Dell XPS 15 with Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, brightness

I searched and found similar issues from years ago but the fixes do not work. I have a new Dell XPS 15 running elementary OS 5.1.7 and the brightness controls do not work. Here's what nvidia-smi is reporting:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.142.00   Driver Version: 450.142.00   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P0     5W /  N/A |      5MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1161      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

...and neofetch:

```
OS: elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera x86\_64

Host: XPS 15 7590 

Kernel: 5.4.0-80-generic 
GPU: NVIDIA NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 

GPU: Intel Device 39b Memory: 2276MiB / 15647MiB
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: To add, the slider moves but there is no change in brightness which seems to be set at max.

Comment: Also tested this with Version 6 Beta 2 and same issue. I really want to use Elementary OS on this new laptop but this is a deal breaker. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a kernel compatibility problem, maybe because your laptop is very new the screen brightness module is not yet built in 5.4.0-80-generic, try installing a more recent kernel.

If you'd like to try i suggest the [Liquorix kernel](https://liquorix.net/) or the [Xanmod kernel](https://xanmod.org/), our maybe just install a mainline kernel with [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline).

Answer (score 1):

Actually it turns out to be an OLED issue with all Linux distros. Returning the laptop and purchasing one that doesn’t have an OLED display.